# App Score from checkboxes

Tags: java, android

I'm coding a quiz app. When I clicked the score button to see if it worked, it showed I got 0 out of 5 right. I put in all the correct answers, but my code didn't tally anything up. What am I missing? I'm not sure what else to add and could really use the guidance as I am a new coder. I appreciate any help you can give.

```
int correctAnswers = 0;

// Start score

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void answers(View view) {

    RadioButton q1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yes_radio_button);
    Boolean q1RightAnswer = q1.isChecked();

    if (q1RightAnswer) {
        correctAnswers += 1;
    }
    CheckBox q2Box1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.box1_checkbox);
    boolean q2Box1RightAnswer = q2Box1.isChecked();

    CheckBox q2Box2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.box2_checkbox);
    boolean q2Box2WrongAnswer = q2Box2.isChecked();

    CheckBox q2Box3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.box3_checkbox);
    boolean q2Box3RightAnswer = q2Box3.isChecked();

    if (q2Box1RightAnswer)

        if (q2Box3RightAnswer) {

            correctAnswers += 1;
        }

    if (q2Box2WrongAnswer) {
        correctAnswers += 0;
    }

    RadioButton q3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.shuri_radio_button);
    Boolean q3RightAnswer = q3.isChecked();

    if (q3RightAnswer) {
        correctAnswers += 1;
    }

    RadioButton q5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.two_radio_button);
    Boolean q5RightAnswer = q5.isChecked();

    if (q5RightAnswer) {
        correctAnswers += 1;
    }

    EditText q4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wakanda);
    String q4RightAnswer = q4.getText().toString();

    if (q4RightAnswer.equals(correctAnswers)) {
        correctAnswers += 1;
    } else {
        // incorrect, do nothing
    }
}


/**
 * This method is called when the score button is clicked.
 */
public void submitScore(View view) {
    Button nameField = (Button) findViewById(R.id.score);
    String score = nameField.getText().toString();
    // Show score message as a toast
    Toast.makeText(this, "You got " + correctAnswers + "/5 correct!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // Exit this method early because there's nothing left to do
    return;

}

}
```

Comment: Boolean q3RightAnswer = q3.isChecked();

        if (q3RightAnswer) {
            correctAnswers += 1;
        }

        RadioButton q5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.two_radio_button);
        Boolean q5RightAnswer = q5.isChecked();

        if (q5RightAnswer) {
            correctAnswers += 1;
        }

        EditText q4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wakanda);

Comment: String q4RightAnswer = q4.getText().toString();

        if (q4RightAnswer.equals(correctAnswers)) {
            correctAnswers += 1;
        } else {
            // incorrect, do nothing
        }
    }


    /**
     * This method is called when the score button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitScore(View view) {
        Button nameField = (Button) findViewById(R.id.score);
        String score = nameField.getText().toString();

Comment: // Show score message as a toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "You got " + correctAnswers + "/5 correct!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Exit this method early because there's nothing left to do
        return;

    }

}

Comment: Please stop commenting to place code and [edit] your question

Comment: When I tried to do that it didn't allow me to. But don't worry, I have no more code to post! Enjoy the rest of your day!

Answer (score 1):

This will never be true

```
q4RightAnswer.equals(correctAnswers)
```

You need to compare matching types, not Strings to integers.

Assuming that's what you're trying to do, either parse the string or convert the int to a String.

You'll get zero printed if none of the checkboxes are marked or `answers()` is never called. For example, what's the difference between the answers method and the submitScore method? Both take a View parameter, so which one is actually assigned to the click event?

I would suggest doing something like

```
RadioButton q1, q3, q5;
EditText q4;
Checkbox qBox1, qBox2;
Button submit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    q1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yes_radio_button);
    // assign other views here 
    submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.score);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            int correctAnswers = 0;
            if (q1.isChecked()) correctAnswers += 1;
            // TODO: check other inputs 

            String q4Text = q4.getText().toString();
            if (q4Text.equals(String.valueOf(correctAnswers)) {
                 correctAnswers += 1;
            } 
            // Toast correct answers 
        } 
    });
}
```

Basically, define all views as class level variables, then immediately set them after a content view is available, then only calculate the score when the button is clicked (in other words, wait for user input). Also, reset the score each time the button is clicked.

Comment: That's fine if it will never be true. I'm aware that it wasn't right, which is why I was trying to get help. While I appreciate you responding, I still don't know how to implement your suggestion.

Comment: You don't know how to use `Integer.parseInt()`? Or something else? I added more code that should demonstrate a [mcve] of just the first question being counted

Comment: No, off the top of my head I don't know how to use it. I'm not you. I haven't been doing this for years, I literally just started a few weeks ago. With a full-time job and a family, I don't get to devote all my time to learning to code sir. I will figure it out either way.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't start learning Java via Android anyway, nor would I really recommend it. In any case, best of luck

Comment: It's not by choice. A potential employer is paying for me to take a 10-month course in 2 months. I'm trying to learn as much as I can while getting all the apps built correctly in that amount of time. I appreciate your help, sir.

Comment: Please try to understand the logic @Ms_Lese what went wrong in your code. This is a good community, if you can just learn, if someone is helping you out, you should be thankful and always take it as a good sign for you to progress in coding. For more help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092212/prevent-repeat-in-shuffle-mode

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. I think it's obvious that I am trying to understand. I wouldn't post questions if I wasn't. I also think it's obvious that I am thankful for the help as I stated this in my post as well as to the person that assisted me.

Comment: @Rohit That comment is for you. Also, not sure how your linked post helps the question other than being a multi choice quiz app

Comment: Sure @cricket_007 I know :) Btw, that was only to understand the quiz logic part. Anyways, I want to know (assuming that your input has been implemented) what does the logcat say?

Comment: @cricket_007 I changed the if statements in my code to mirror your example, but how will it determine which answers are right for each question? I tried to search for similar problems but didn't find a solution that fits. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Disregard, I figured it out.